# Which is the best tool or software for OCR text extraction scanned Bank Statement pdf to text?

Tags: pdf, ocr, data-extraction

My Requirement is to extract the text from scanned pdf using OCR technique for Multiple Bank statements with different formats.

There are might be many libraries and tools are present to extract data or through api, but facing alignment/space or newline text issues. I'm getting a single space or the next line between each word.
for example, pdfplumber python library works for the normal(not scanned pdf) bank pdf by adjusting tolerance and density for space issues.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Ci4.png trying for a similar alignment result for Scanned PDF.

Comment: Are you interested in developing an application or an end-user ready product?  What budget for the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The LEADTOOLS [Document Converter](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-converter) recognizes text using an OCR engine while alignment and formatting is maintained in conversion by using Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG) to accurately generate the output. Generated TXT output can be configured to be [formatted](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/ft/textdocumentoptions-formatted.html) to follow the input’s spacing and margins. You can download a free evaluation of the toolkit from the website [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads) and you can find a number of Document Converter tutorial for different platforms [here](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/tutorials/home.html#/platform). (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)